# node mmmagic detectFile returns inode/x-empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mmmagic

I am trying to detect my uploaded file type. There are two files im uploading:

```
input.xls
```

And

```
input.ods
```

In node i run the following code:

```
var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
magic.detectFile(req.filePath, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        waterfallCallback(customError.invalidInputMessage('File not uploaded'));
        return;
    }

    var fileType;
    var error;
    switch(result) {
        case 'text/plain':
        case 'text/csv':
        case 'application/csv':
            fileType = 'csv';
            break;
        case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
        case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
            fileType = 'excel';
            break;
        case 'application/vnd.ms-office':
            error = customError.invalidInputMessage('Fileformat not supported');
            break;
        case 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet':
            fileType = 'ods';
            break;
        default:
            error = customError.invalidInputMessage('Only xlsx, xls and csv file types are supported');
            return;
    }

    waterfallCallback(error, fileType);
});
```

Debugging this code says that the file type is :

```
inode/x-empty
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Are your files empty?

Comment: @mscdex no they have 3 rows of data

Comment: Is it possible the file isn't (completely) written when you go to check the uploaded file? Did you try running this same code locally in isolation with the same file (outside of the upload scenario to make sure there is no race condition)?

Comment: @mscdex i assume this is the issue ive posted another question regarding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312637/node-next-is-called-before-end-of-stream